# Laravel where clause in controller

Tags: laravel, if-statement, eloquent, where-clause

im new in programming and laravel, I want to ask how to show data from the Reqlowongan table that has not been filled in the Isilowongan table by detecting it with the mahasiswa_id attribute in Isilowongan table with the current mahasiswa_id being logged in. So when the user login, they only see Reqlowongan that they dont register in Isilowongan (Reqlowongan is my form, and Isilowongan is the answer for the form that user fill)  How to do it?

this is my table :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vWcm.png

this is my controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $role = auth()->user()->role;
    $id = auth()->user()->id;
    if($role =='mahasiswa'){
        $lowongan = Reqlowongan::all();
        return view('indexMhs', compact(['lowongan']));
    }if($role =='instansi'){
        $lowongan = auth()->user()->instansi->reqlowongan;
        return view('indexIns', compact(['lowongan']));  
    }else{
        $lowongan = Reqlowongan::all();
        return view('IndexKp', compact(['lowongan']));  
    }
}
```

this is my blade

```
@foreach($lowongan as $lowongan)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
            <td>{{ $lowongan->instansi->nama_instansi}}</th>
            <td>{{ $lowongan->jenis_lowongan}}</th>
            <td>{{ $lowongan->created_at->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="/instansi/{{$lowongan->id}}/list_mahasiswa" class="badge badge-warning ml-2">DAFTAR </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
```

i already try using where clause and if clause, but i dont know how and i cant do it, can you help me please?

Comment: Very few people know what a "Reqlowongan" or a "mahasiswa" is, Yos. This means fewer chances of getting a good answer. Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by replacing your table-names/fields/variables with generic, English language (or programming) terms like "Foo" and "Bar" or "Students" or "Customers". Also, have all the data required to answer the question in the question itself (not as an imgur image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after find role from user table
in if statement you must join table together like that

```
public function index()
{
    $role = auth()->user()->role;
    $id = auth()->user()->id;
    if($role =='mahasiswa'){
        $lowongan = user::join('mahasiswa','mahasiswa.user_id','user.id')
                  ->join('isi_lowongan','isi_lowonan.mahasiswa_id','mahasiswa.id')
               ->join('req_lowongan','req_lowonan.id','isi_lowonan.reqlowongan_id') 
            ->join('instansi','instansi.id','req_lowonan.instansi_id')
            //->where('user.id','$id')
        ->select('req_lowonan.*','instansi.nama_instansi as nama_instansi');
        return view('indexMhs', compact(['lowongan']));
    }if($role =='instansi'){
        $lowongan = user::join('instansi','instansi.user_id','user.id')               
     ->join('req_lowongan','req_lowonan.instansi_id','instansi.id') 
        ->select('req_lowonan.*','instansi.nama_instansi as nama_instansi');
        return view('indexIns', compact(['lowongan']));  
    }else{
        $lowongan = user::join('instansi','instansi.user_id','user.id')               
     ->join('req_lowongan','req_lowonan.instansi_id','instansi.id') 
        ->select('req_lowonan.*','instansi.nama_instansi as nama_instansi');
        return view('IndexKp', compact(['lowongan']));  
    }
}
```

Done

```
@foreach($lowongan as $item)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
            <td>{{ $item->nama_instansi}}</th>
            <td>{{ $item->jenis_lowongan}}</th>
            <td>{{ $item->created_at->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="/instansi/{{$item->id}}/list_mahasiswa" class="badge badge-warning ml-2">DAFTAR </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
```

Comment: i try to copy the code and fix some typo for the tables, but its not working, even its not selecting any of my records

Comment: in namespace type ..... use your address model for table

Comment: i do anything and still confused